# JQuery Click class to append and remove overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm pretty new to Jquery (and coding for that matter) and I'm trying to do this:

When a menu item that has sub-menu items is clicked on an overlay fades in (creating a modal effect) so that the focus is on the sub menu. I have been able to achieve this, but am not sure on the best route to close it.

A user should be able to click on the overlay and both close the sub-menu and remove the overlay. They should also be able to do the same thing by clicking on the main menu item. The class I will be assigning the menu items that have sub-menu items is ".jrm-menu-categories" See code below:

```
//Add our overlay to the body and fade it in.
  $('.jrm-menu-categories').click(function()    {
    $('#wrap_all').append('<div id="overlay-2"></div>');
    $('#overlay-2').fadeIn(300);
    });

// remove overlay when overlay is clicked
$(function(){// document.ready shorthand
    $(document).on('click','#overlay-2',function() {
        $('#overlay-2').fadeOut('3000',function(){//use 3000 in place of 300m
            $('#overlay-2').remove();
        });    
        return false;
    });
});
```

How can I achieve what I mentioned above? I'm stumped!

Thanks in advance!!!

---------------------------Update-------------------------------

Hey thanks for all the answers guys! However, maybe I need to clarify. I already am able to remove the overlay when it is clicked. However I am trying to link the overlay to the ".jrm-menu-categories" class and vice versa.

So when the class is clicked the overlay pops up. (on my dev site a sub-menu also pops up that has a higher z-index than the overlay). now here is what I'm trying to do. When the overlay is clicked, the menu should close and the overlay should hide. An alternative way that I also want is that if the original menu with the class is clicked, the menu should close and the overlay should hide.
I hope that makes sense.

I was thinking that a .toggle would work, because I can't add another click function to the class in order to close the overlay because they cancel each other out. But I don't know how to use the toggle function.

Thanks again! Big help here! :)

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for it.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshed your code with this:

```
//Add our overlay to the body and fade it in.
  $('.jrm-menu-categories').click(function()    {
    $('#wrap_all').append('<div id="overlay-2"></div>').hide().fadeIn(300);
    });

// remove overlay when overlay is clicked
$(function(){// document.ready shorthand
    $(document).on('click','#overlay-2',function() {
        $('#overlay-2').fadeOut('3000',function(){//use 3000 in place of 300m
            $(this).remove();
        });    
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Don't remove the overlay menu instead of use `hide()` in jquery;

```
   $(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#overlay-2',function() {
            $('#overlay-2').fadeOut('3000',function(){//use 3000 in place of 300m
                $('#overlay-2').hide();
            });    
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$('.jrm-menu-categories').click(function()    {
$('#wrap_all').append('<div id="overlay-2">overlay</div>');
$('#overlay-2').fadeIn(300);
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#overlay-2',function() {
        $('#overlay-2').fadeOut('3000',function()
        {
            $('#overlay-2').remove();
        });    
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Or Refer to this fiddle:

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zgm9d/7/)

Comment: Or you can even use $('#overlay-2').hide() if it suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

If an overlay is supposed to open multiple times, it's better to keep it there at the bottom of the page always. Instead of creating and removing the div, showing/hiding will be better to do that.

here is the example:

```
<div id="wrap_all">
    <a href="#" class="jrm-menu-categories">Click Here</a>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#overlay{display:none; height:100%; width:100%; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); z-index:100}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.jrm-menu-categories').click(function(e){
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('click','#overlay',function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('3000');
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M8sqe/